# How to find out active members during a specific period (month) in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

In the following real-world scenario:

Users come to a club (e.g. : gym) and purchase a membership for an indefinite amount of time and after a specified amount of time the membership is cancelled.
After the membership cancelled, the same user at  a later time can purchase another membership for a  one or more months.

I have an event table in which the event of starting and stoping a membership is being logged.

**membership_events**

- member_id : int
- event_type_id: int
- event_time: timeuuid

PK (member_id, event_type_id, event_time)

One thing which can happen is that a member can have multiple memberships:

- 2015.1 - 2015.5
- 2016.1 - 2016.3
- 2016.5 - ?

How can i find out the via cassandra which is the number of active memberships within a specified month?

**Sample data**

User1

memberships:

- 2015.4 - 2015.6
- 2016.1  - 2016.3

User 2

memberships

- 2015.7 - 2015.8
- 2015.9 - 2016.3

User 3

memberships

- 2015.8 - 2015.12
- 2016.5 - ?

Active memberships for the month  2016.1:

- User 1
- User 2

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact that your PK consists of

> PK (member_id, event_type_id, event_time)

makes your question hard to solve, and at least inefficient because you need to query all partitions without being able to filter any record at database level (basically you must perform a `SELECT` without a `WHERE` clausole).

Just to alleviate this problem, I would transform your model in something like:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    dummy int,
    event_start timestamp,
    event_stop timestamp,
    member_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (dummy_partition, event_start, event_stop)
);
```

This table makes use of a *dummy* partition (this is an **HOTSPOT**!!! Don't try this at home... and in production...) that would allow to specify something like `WHERE dummy = 0 AND ...` which you can exploit by writing something like

```
SELECT member_id FROM events WHERE dummy = 0 AND event_start <= '2016-01-01' AND event_stop > '2016-01-01';
```

to get the records for the 2016.1 period, assuming that an indefinite membership is stored with a far timestamp (`2100-01-01` should be far enough).

With this, you'll extract the member_ids that are active in the 2016.1 month, and the results will eventually contain some member_id duplicates. You'll need to filter them manually at application level.

The truth is that you should rethink you model, and something like creating a new table that holds membership month by month should be the best option you have, and *probably* it is the best way to solve that specific problem in the C* way.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for the reply. The transformation that you've provided, as you've said, is just for test purposes, not for production. About rethinking the model, I tried to expose the model with the gym to try to make the question easy to grasp. I guess it is easy enough to state the problem that I'm dealing with (the membership can be renewed and lasts a varialble amount of time).